# Java Web Start deprecation

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp, java-11, java-ws

I'm little worrying about the removal of Java web Start from Java 11.

Any special reason behind javaws removal ? And share the best alternatives for javaws.

Answer (score 2):

[IcedTea-Web](https://icedtea.classpath.org/wiki/IcedTea-Web) seems to be a go-to replacement for Java Web Start.

Reason for removing it can be found in [JEP-289](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/289)

> To run a Java applet in a web browser requires the use of a browser plug-in. As of late 2015, however, many browser vendors have either already removed plug-in support or else announced timelines for such removal. Once browser plug-ins disappear, there will be no reason to use the Applet API.

Comment: Marcin.. Thank you !! Is Oracle suggesting any alternatives for Java web start from Java 11 ?